# How to increment a variable in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I need to create an assembly program that prints:
0
01
012
0123
...
0123456789
It seems like I need to create a variable that I can increment that stops the code once I get to it so I can go back and start again, this is my attempt so far. I can already get it to print 0123456789 ten times but it's getting it to count up is the problem.
Here is that code

```
.MODEL MEDIUM
.STACK
.DATA
number DB 1
.CODE
.STARTUP
 mov bl,10
nextline: mov dl,'0' ; '0' is ASCII 48
nextchar: mov ah,02h ; print ASCII char in dl
 int 021h
 inc dl
 cmp dl,':';‘:' is ASCII for 10
 jnz nextchar

 push dx ; save value of dl and dh on stack
 mov ah,02h ; print ASCII char in dl
 mov dl,13 ; carriage return (move to start of line)
 int 021h
 mov dl,10 ; line feed (next line)
int 021h
 pop dx ; restore value in dl (and dh)
 dec bl
 jnz nextline
 .EXIT
END
```

And here is my attempt at making it count up, perhaps I don't fully understand how variables work yet

```
.MODEL MEDIUM
.STACK
.DATA
number DB '1' ;changed from 1 to '1'
.CODE
.STARTUP
 mov bl,10
nextline: mov dl,'0' ; '0' is ASCII 48
nextchar: mov ah,02h ; print ASCII char in dl
 int 021h
 inc dl
 cmp dl,number;‘:' is ASCII for 10
 jnz nextchar

 push dx ; save value of dl and dh on stack
 mov ah,02h ; print ASCII char in dl
 mov dl,13 ; carriage return (move to start of line)
 int 021h
 mov dl,10 ; line feed (next line)
int 021h
 pop dx ; restore value in dl (and dh)
 dec bl
 add number,1 ;moved to outer loop
 jnz nextline
 .EXIT
END
```

Comment: `cmp dl,number` <-- You're comparing numbers to characters. `1 != '1'`.

Comment: @Michael I changed number to represent a character but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: Shouldn't `add number,1` be in the outer loop instead of in the inner loop?

Comment: @fuz i updated my number variable to represent the character 1 instead, or should i be changing dl?

Comment: @EvanScanlon I know.  But it is important that you add what exactly you changed since there are multiple things that could be meant by this description.  Show us which line you changed and what the new content is.

Comment: @fuz i've commented the parts i've edited which is line 4 and line 23

Comment: Cool!  Let's see if we get the other issues resolved, too.

Comment: If you're only using the 1-char-at-a-time DOS calls, you don't need `number` in memory, just a register.  And yes, you want a double-nested loop.  Or probably more efficiently, set up a `$`-terminated string in memory and pass it to a DOS print-string system call.  Then you just need one loop that adds a new digit and puts a `$` farther out.

Comment: @fuz honestly not too sure how to progress from here, can't see what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, do yourself a favour and change the name of your variable from *number* to ***character*** since that's what it is now that you've followed the advice by others.

---

With the help of Michael you've already fixed a few things to your code. What's still posing problems is next part of the code:

> ```
> add character,1 ;moved to outer loop
> jnz nextline
> ```

As written, the outer loop will stop when the byte-sized *character* increments from the value 255 to 0.

You need to limit the raising of *character*; up to a maximum of '9'.
You can use the `cmp` instruction for that:

```
add character, 1
cmp character, '9'
jbe nextline
```

The `jbe` instruction will keep jumping back (looping) for as long as the *character* is below or equal to '9'.
It also avoids using ugly constructs like:

> ```
> ‘:' is ASCII for 10
> ```

---

There's no more need for a counter in `BL` and preserving `DX` around the newline part is redundant.
This is your revised code:

```
.MODEL MEDIUM
.STACK
.DATA
character DB '0'
.CODE
.STARTUP
 mov ah, 02h         ; print ASCII char in dl
nextline:
 mov dl, '0'
nextchar:
 int 21h
 inc dl
 cmp dl, character
 jbe nextchar

 mov dl, 13          ; carriage return
 int 21h
 mov dl, 10          ; line feed
 int 21h
 add character, 1
 cmp character, '9'
 jbe nextline
.EXIT
END
```

Take note that *character* now starts at '0' (and not '1').